# Can Visual Studio Code be configured to launch with nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon, visual-studio-code

I have installed `nodemon` as a global package in my system. 
It works when I executed `nodemon` in cmd.

But when I am using vscode with this `launch.json` file, vscode throws this exception:

> request launch: runtime executable XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\nodemon does not exists

the launch.json is:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "app.js",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": [],
        "cwd": ".",
        "runtimeExecutable": nodemon,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "externalConsole": false,
        "preLaunchTask": "",
        "sourceMaps": false,
        "outDir": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5858
    }
]
}
```

when I erase the nodemin in `runtimeExecutable` it runs perfectly with node

Comment: VS Code expects an absolute path for the "runtimeExecutable". So on OS X using "/usr/local/bin/nodemon" will make the launch config work. However, at the end of the debug session VS Code will kill nodemon which is not the intent of using nodemon in the first place. That's why the answer below is a much better approach.

Comment: This helped me :)  => https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/nodemon

Answer (score 79):

First, install nodemon as a dev dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

**For newer versions of VS Code** set up your `.vscode/launch.json` file like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "nodemon",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
        "restart": true,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }]
}
```

The most important pieces are the `runtimeExecutable` property that points to the nodemon script and the `program` property that points to your entry point script.

**If you use an older VS Code** (which you shouldn't), try this launch configuration:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch with nodemon",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
      "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/app.js"],
      "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The most important pieces are the `program` property that points to the nodemon script and the `args` property that points to your normal entry point script.

Comment: Any idea how to pass in parameters to nodemon, such as `--watch /server/**.ts --exec ts-node server/server.ts` for example? Typically it's just one big line in either package.json scripts or cmd line. `nodemon --watch server/**/*.ts --ignore server/**/*.spec.ts --exec ts-node server/server.ts`

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but you should be able to pass all the arguments you need in the "args" array. For the example you mentioned, try using `"args": ["--watch", "/server/**.ts", "--ignore", "server/**/*.spec.ts", "--exec", "ts-node", "server/server.ts"]`

Comment: any idea how to do this with babel-node/es6? this is the actual nodemon command I want to run: `nodemon src/shim-host/index.js --exec babel-node --babel-preset-es2015` but it's not working when I add the relevant file to `program`, and the nodemon arguments to `runtimeArgs`

Comment: @devdropper87: You need to change "args", not "runtimeArgs". Try this: `"args": ["${workspaceRoot}/src/shim-host/index.js", "--exec", "babel-node", "--babel-preset-es2015"]`

Comment: @AdrianT I tried that, here's the nodemon command generated (which then crashes): `[nodemon] starting babel-node ${workspaceRoot}/src/shim-host/index.js --babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: Ah I see thanks, but then how would `nodemon` be leveraged in that case?

Comment: @devdropper87: You are correct, I probably need another coffee. Actually the answer in my first comment was correct. I will delete the second (wrong) answer. Make sure you are using the latest version of VS Code and specify `"version": "0.2.0"` in your launch config. I just updated the snippet in the answer to include the `version` property.

Comment: Can anyone provide a working solution to this showing the args? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: This seems to not work- running VSCode 1.30.2. [Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445633/2483138) worked for me

Comment: @ABMagil I updated the answer to include the correct configuration for newer versions of VS Code. I also made sure it works with a locally installed nodemon, as opposed to a global install, as per the default VS Code config.

Comment: This should really be how VSCode generates the configuration based on the system. If nodemon is in the workspaces node_modules folder than use one from this otherwise check for a global installed one generate the config to use that.

Answer (score 50):

I couldn't get @AdrianT's answer working with the debugger attached. It seems like there's a newer built-in supported way to do this:

1. Open the Launch Configuration dropdown and select "Add configuration..."
2. Select "Node.js: Nodemon Setup"

It will add something like this to your launch.json:

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "nodemon",
        "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
        "restart": true,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

Make sure your "program" setting is your correct entry point script.

You need to install nodemon globally to get this to work (npm install -g nodemon) (as per [the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging.md))

Your app now runs and you can set breakpoints which will be hit and the console logs to the integrated terminal window.

Note that terminating the debug session only terminates the program to debug, not nodemon itself. To terminate nodemon, press Control-C in the integrated terminal.

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer as it's the correct way to do this now.

Comment: If you don't like having to run a global `nodemon` you can also install `nodemon` using `npm` and then set `"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",`

Comment: what about flags, do they go in runtimeExecutable

Comment: If this helps anyone, make sure that you pass correct JS file in `program` parameter. In my case it was `\bin\www.js` and not `app.js`.

Answer (score 14):

In Visual studio code create a launch config:

```
{
    "name": "Attach",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 5858,
    "restart": true
}
```

run nodemon from the command line: `nodemon --debug server.js`

Now 'Attach' from VC and vuala.

Comment: Why port 5858? If nodemon is running on 3000. Tried 3000 and it doesn't do anything (no error nothing) neither seem to work. @Yevgeni

Comment: So I passed the `--debug` flag to nodemon and I see remote debuggin on `Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858` but strangely VSCode connects to something, but doesn't seem to hit breakpoints

Answer (score 5):

Attaching is definitely an easy option. In order to make sure that your code breaks, make sure you run nodemon with `--inspect-brk` (node 8+), e.g.:

```
nodemon --inspect-brk src/app.js
```

After launching nodemon will log the port open for debug connections:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/someUUID
```

You can take that port in order to build your launch config which is quite simple:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach",
  "port": 9229,
  "restart": true
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solutions Adrian and Mathew suggested. They seem to work perfectly if your are on macOS (maybe also on Linux). On Windows, maybe Mathew's solution is more stable. Combining both to have a solution that could be compatible with both macOS, Windows and Linux, and makes sure that we don't face with errors like "PATH not found", I found that using globally installed nodemon for **debugging** seems to be much more stable.

- Install nodemon globally (if you haven't done it before) `npm i -g nodemon`
- Add the following to the `.vscode/launch.json`

```
    {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Debug App_Name",
          "skipFiles": [
            "./path/of/file/to/skip/when/debugging"
          ],
          "program": "app.js",
          "restart": true,
          "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
          "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
      ]
    }
```

We, of course, can still install `nodemon` locally and run it while developing.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me **without global installs** and using typescript:

```
{
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "name": "nodemon",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
    "request": "launch",
    "restart": true,
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
    "type": "pwa-node",
    "args": ["--config", "nodemon.json"] //remove --config if you don't have one
}
```

In order to don't have problems with `ts-node`, in `nodemon.json` I added it:

```
{
    "execMap": {
        "ts": "npx ts-node"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will let you run it on the file currently open in the editor WITHOUT installing `nodemon` as a dependency. This makes it convenient to keep in a template project.

The `cwd` and `program` are set so that the working directory is the one containing the file, and the program is the filename without a path. This makes it compatible with monorepos because it will then search back up the file tree for the correct `tsconfig.json`, `package.json`, `node_modules`, etc.

E.g. if the currently opened file is `/path/to/some-file.ts`, this is equivalent to running in the shell like:

```bash
cd /path/to
npx -y nodemon some-file.ts
```

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "nodemon",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npx",
      "runtimeArgs": ["-y", "nodemon"],
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "restart": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, currently it can't. But I managed to get this somewhat working using nodemon. I start it from Grunt . But an equivalent command line should do the same.

**EDIT**: After an evening of testing I can say that below approach is still somewhat flakey :S, attaching fails intermittedly and sometimes breakpoints are ignored.

**EDIT2**: You can also specify an non default debug port in Gruntfile using `['--debug-brk=5860']` for `nodeArgs`. I've been also advised to use `--debug-brk` instead of `--debug`. Perhaps this will remove the current flakeyness. I'll come back and mention here if it helps (I've currently switched project).

In case this might help anyone it's working with below settings in Current VS Code version (e.g. v0.10.6) on Windows 10. But it'll probably work on Mac too (I might check later). But note that I sometimes have to trigger a rebuild by changing+saving a file before the debugger picks it up.

`/.vscode/launch.json`

```
{
"configurations": [{
    "name": "Launch",
    "outDir": null

},{
    "name": "Attach",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 5858
}]
```

}

`/Gruntfile.js`

```
nodemon : {
    dev : {
    script : 'launcher.js'
    },
    options : {
        ignore : ['node_modules/**', 'Gruntfile.js'],
               nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
        env : { PORT : '4123'
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the debug port 5858 is the default since it's not specified here (note it ís in `launch.json` above.)

Comment: I've created this VSCode feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2103

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/nodemon

The above link helped me to successfully debug nodemon + express app. The steps are well explained there.

launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Node: Nodemon",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "restart": true,
        "protocol": "inspector",
    }
]
```

}

npm script

```
"dev-server": "nodemon ***--inspect*** server.js"
```

Steps:

1. Run the server, using npm script. Please note --inspect arg in
   the script
2. Start visual code debugger, A prompt will be shown to
   select the node server process
3. select the node server process

Now you should be able to debug.

if it did not help you, then please have a look at the official doc, the config options are explained there.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-support-for-npm-and-other-tools

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to set up nodemon with an `express-generator` created ExpressJS  project on windows, this is what worked for me when nodemon is installed as a local dev dependency (e.g. `npm install nodemon --save-dev`)

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch with Nodemon",
    "runtimeExecutable": "node",
    "runtimeArgs": ["${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js"],
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\www",
    "env" : {
        "DEBUG": "myapp:server"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! As of a recent update you can attach the debugger to a running Nodemon process. [This page has more information](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_node-debugging). Search for nodemon on the page to see the instructions.

Comment: There is nothing on https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging mentioning nodemon...

Comment: There was in June 2016: https://web.archive.org/web/20160630150344/https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 0):

I use the Node Exec plugin. It allows you to run and stop a node app in vcs by pressing F8 and F9 (applies on open file in editor). This could help as a (temporary) workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**Nodemon as local dependency**

I also could not get @Adrian T's answer to work right away. But it is only a small detail, that has to be changed to make it work. So here we go:

1. create a *launch.json* file in a top-level *.vscode* folder
2. open the file in VS Code
3. use the build in button *Add Configuration* - that will be rendered in the editor - to add a config for *Node.js: Nodemon Setup*
4. in the generated config change the key *runtimeExecutable*:

```js
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",

// diff from Adrian T
-- "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
++ "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
```

You are now using the executables from your local dependencies (see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306168/what-is-the-purpose-of-bin-folder-in-node-modules))

There is also an answer by Martin from earlier underneath this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46445633/7074015) (just to be correct):

> If you don't like having to run a global nodemon you can also install nodemon using npm and then set "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon", – Martin Feb 22 '18 at 22:25

**Nodemon as global dependency**

`"runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",` will only work if the executable of *nodemon* itself is part of the environment variable *PATH* (not `%appdata% or the like thereof). As this is mostly not the case, you would need to specify the absolute path (see the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-support-for-npm-and-other-tools)).

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything,
Just open Powershell as administrator and write

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

and then enter A

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Install nodemon as a dev dependency.

```bash
npm install -D -E nodemon
```

Options:

- **-D option:** To save as dev dependency
- **-E option:** To install exact version

### 2. Add a `nodemon.json` file in the root of the project with the following content.

```json
{
    "restartable": "rs",
    "ignore": [".git", "node_modules/**/node_modules"],
    "verbose": true,
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node --harmony"
    },
    "watch": ["src/", ".env"],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "ext": "js,json",
    "delay": 500
}
```

For more information, see the official documentation [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files).

### 3. Add a script to `package.json`.

```bash
npm pkg set scripts.dev="nodemon --config nodemon.json"
```

### 4. Add launch config in `.vscode/launch.json`.

Content:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Run Nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "dev"],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        }
    ]
}
```

To see documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes).

The `envFile` option is optional. I use it because I am using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv).

Answer (score -1):

It works fine for me, in the main Terminal.
Do not use VS code terminal, use the main system terminal.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.