# Why do people usually call the node_modules/.bin content as "binaries"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, bin

If they are just text files with commands in them, and they usually call a js file. The only binary involved in this is the node. Why people usually call them as "binaries" and why the folder's name is ".bin" instead of ".cmd" or anything else?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306168/what-is-the-purpose-of-bin-folder-in-node-modules

Comment: The word *"binary"* comes from the world of compiled languages. The executable programs generated by the compiler are not text, and they are usually named "binaries" because of that. The meaning of the term moved into the world of interpreted languages even if their executables are not binaries but text. It usually denotes the entry-point scripts (those that are meant to be invoked).