# Purpose of the .bin directory within node_modules? What are binaries?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, cpu-architecture

What's the purpose of the `.bin` directory within `node_modules`?

In [another question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306168/what-is-the-purpose-of-bin-folder-in-node-modules) the answerer stated:

*"it's where your binaries (executables) from your node modules are located."*

So additionally can someone explain to me the following: *What are binaries/executables*?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of .bin folder in node\_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306168/what-is-the-purpose-of-bin-folder-in-node-modules)

Comment: Joao, I referred to an answer to that question in this question, and I asked because that information was missing from answers to that question. I know it contains binaries but I wanted to know what binaries are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Binary or executable** files are files which have *already been compiled for your specific computer architecture* and, once installed, these files can be **ran directly** on your computer. Common instruction set architectures are: **X86** and **ARM,** which most computer processors are based upon. Contrary to binary files, **source** files are the *actual source code itself* and these files need to be compiled prior to installing.

As for the `.bin` directory, within `./node_modules/.bin`, this *directory stores all the executables of your `node_modules`* for which your project is dependent upon to run. This allows your project to just *'run'* the libraries which are necessary, for your project, without you having to worry about compiling these files yourself. By compiling I mean *transforming the source code down to executable code* (machine code) which can understood by your computer's underlying processor.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 3):

[According to npm docmentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders.html#executables)

When in global mode, executables are linked into {prefix}/bin on Unix, or directly into {prefix} on Windows.

When in local mode, executables are linked into ./node_modules/.bin so that they can be made available to scripts run through npm. (For example, so that a test runner will be in the path when you run npm test.)

Binaries are executable files ( the compiled version of your file for a specific computer architecture) and once installed they can be run directly from your machine