# What do the files in bin folder actually used for?

Tags: node.js, binaries

I am currently working on a node project that requires **eslint** as a dependency. Hence, a file named `eslint` and `eslint.cmd` was created automatically in the *root_directory/node_modules/.bin* folder.

The content of the **eslint** file is -

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../eslint/bin/eslint.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../eslint/bin/eslint.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Can someone give a line-to-line explaination to what exactly this code is doing?

I read the answer on [What is the purpose of .bin folder in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25306168/10816549) 
Still couldn't figure out how this code does all that is stated in the answers.

node version - 12.10.0
npm version - 6.10.3