# How to install Phaser3 documents

Tags: phaser-framework, jsdoc

I can't seem to figure out how to install the documents for offline use. I wanted to download them to an external drive `d:`. I used Phaser [GitHub](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-docs) and went to the `D:` drive and created a folder called `phaser` and then cloned the GitHub repo.

Now I have `D:\phaser\phaser`.

I also installed jsDocs using `npm install -g jsdoc` and it was installed at `C:\Users\jfire\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jsdoc`

How do I now use jsDocs to show the phaser documents? I tried running `npm run gen` from the `D:\phaser\phaser` folder but get this error

```
$ npm run gen
npm ERR! missing script: gen

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jfire\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-16T23_58_11_318Z-debug.log
```

I'm not really sure how this kind of stuff works but need to get these documents available offline for viewing. Any help would be appreciated.

Adding error code from `npm install`

```
jfire@DESKTOP-FOR4DMS MINGW64 /d/phaser/phaser (master)
$ npm install
npm WARN tar EINVAL: invalid argument, futime
npm WARN tar EINVAL: invalid argument, futime
npm WARN tar EINVAL: invalid argument, futime
npm WARN tar EINVAL: invalid argument, futime
npm WARN tar EINVAL: invalid argument, futime
npm WARN tar EINVAL: invalid argument, futime
npm WARN tar EINVAL: invalid argument, futime
npm WARN tar EINVAL: invalid argument, futime
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path D:\phaser\phaser\node_modules\@babel\parser
npm ERR! dest D:\phaser\phaser\node_modules\@babel\.parser.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\phaser\phaser\node_modules\@babel\parser' -> 'D:\phaser\phaser\node_modules\@babel\.parser.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jfire\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-17T01_44_36_990Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need `npm install` (without parameter) in order to install the scripts declared in `package.json`, with the `node_modules/.bin` folder in the path.

Then `npm run gen` would run the `gen` script.

Comment: So I did that from the `D:\phaser\phaser folder. I added my errors to my question. I also ran `npm install` from the jsDocs folder which created a `.bin` folder but still not sure what to do.

Comment: @Justin If you see a `gen` script in the `.bin` folder, make sure the full path of that folder is included in your `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: in the `.bin` folder are threee files `jsdoc` `jsdoc.cmd` and `jsdoc.ps1`. I don't see a `gen` script. Unless its one of those.

Comment: @Justin If the `.bin` is in your `%PATH%`, test what a `npm run gen` would give you. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57082990/6309.

Comment: By running `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"` I get a list of directories in my PATH to include these two `/Users/jfire/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jsdoc` and 
`/Users/jfire/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/.bin`. However using `npm run gen` just gives the `npm ERR! missing script: gen` error

Comment: @Justin OK. Strange, considering your `package.json` does define the gen function: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-docs/blob/3bc4ffd72a41aad32b6c8713bb73abda063ecf81/package.json#L9

Comment: Ok so I never cloned the docs from the phaser3-docs github. I only cloned the phaser3 github. Now I have cloned the docs and then I put the `phaser` folder in the root of `phaser3-docs`. Now it looks like `D:\phaser\phaser3-docs\phaser`. I also was getting python errors so I installed Python. Then I was getting Visual Studio Errors so I installed Visual Studios. Then I was getting some kind of VS v140 error so I installed that too. I finally was able to run `npm install` from the `D:\phaser\phaser3-docs` path without error. Now I still can't run `npm run gen` though. Extremely frustrating.